# How to use Dropzone with Nextjs? Error: Invalid dropzone element

Tags: next.js, dropzone.js, dropzone

I'm trying to use Dropzone with Next.js but getting this error message.

```
export default function UploadFiles() {
> 67 | let myDropzone = new Dropzone("my-form");
     |                 ^
  68 | myDropzone.on("addedfile", (file) => {
  69 |   console.log(`File added: ${file.name}`);
  70 | });
```

This is my code:

```
return (
    <section>
      <form
        action="/file-upload"
        class="dropzone"
        id="my-awesome-dropzone"
      ></form>
    </section>
  );
```